# How to pass two separate instances of a class at a time in JAVA to sort some data in that classes

Tags: java, sorting, comparison

I have a class called FACTORY. The factory class contains a variable named Time which has some value. I want to pass two instances of my class FACTORY like (FACTORY A, FACTORY B) to sort the data available.
The below code is in swift. How can I implement the same in JAVA.

Code in Swift

'''

```
self.factories = self.factories.sorted { (first: FACTORY, second: FACTORY) in
                var times = [first.Time]

                var firstDate: Time? = nil
                for time in times {
                    if let dateFromTime =  DateFormatter.iso8601TimeFormatter.date(from: time) {
                    }
                }

                times = [second.Time]
                var secondDate: Time? = nil
                for time in times {
                    if let dateFromTime = DateFormatter.iso8601TimeFormatter.date(from: time) {
                    }
                }
                if firstDate != nil && secondDate != nil {
                    return firstDate! < secondDate!
                }
                return false
            }
```

'''

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: @CodeMatrix  I don't have any idea on how to pass two instances of single class and sort as I'm new to Java.

Comment: "I'm new to Java." => Then you have to learn Java. Go and buy some books, work your way through many tutorials, code as much as you can, etc. Until you are good enough to create the code of your question. SO is not a please-write-the-code-for-me-site!

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback, and welcome to upvote privileges :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how to sort the factories by the value of their time.

```
List<Factory> sortedFactories = factories.stream().sorted((first, second) -> {
            final long time1 = first.getTime();
            final long time2 = second.getTime();
            return time1-time2;
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How does it work:
In the first line, your tranform theList factories to a java8 Stream class.
After that, you start the sorting algorithm (with the method sorted((first, decond) -> [...]);
The java8's sorting algorithm work like that:
The algorithm call your Comparator (here the comparator is the lamba expression (first, decond) -> {...});

And your comparator must return:

```
A negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as the
first argument is less than, equal to, or greater than the
second.
```

And your list is sorted magically :D

And finally you transform the Stream to a list with .collect(Collectors.toList());

I hope that I help you.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I am actually working on android. The stream class is only supported in API Level > 24. Any other alternative. I need it to support till API 21